# Android: Searching simple library for drawing undirected graphs

Tags: java, android, directed-graph

I am searching for a simple library to draw undirected graphs. 
I like to show a simple network map in my Android App, containing some nodes and the links between them.

To make it more clear, I'm thinking of something simple like that:

```
Graph graph = new Graph();
Node a = new Node("Name of node A"); // name should be displayed
Node b = new Node("Name of node B");
Link ab = new Link(a,b, "Name of the link"); // name should be displayed
graph.add(a);
graph.add(b);
graph.add(ab);
ab.setColor(Color.RED);
Bitmap result = graph.getBitmap(500, 500); // 500,500 = size in Px
```

There are some graph libraries for Java available, but I haven't found one that works with Android. (They're all using Java UI stuff which is not available in Android.)

Does anybody know about such a library that works with Android?[image]

Comment: have managed to find a lib for this purpose?